# CEP Esper - how to return absence Event when trigger within some specific time

Tags: java, complex-event-processing, esper

This query is very helpful to me
select * from pattern [every (timer:interval(10 sec) and not EventX(id="001"))];
But i want the return value EventX which is id = 001 when event trigger.

Anyone have good idea how to modify above query, Please help for this.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand correctly you want the last EventX as part of the output? If that is the case here is a sample subquery in the select....

```
select *, (select * from EventX(id='001')#lastevent) as lastx
from pattern [every (timer:interval(10 sec) and not EventX(id="001"))]
```